# Snapchat discover animation

Tags: android, animation

I would like to make something similar like snapchat discover animation i mean when i click the button take the whole screen and the video start how can i do something like this to start a video view after all :

```
direction Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        ScaleAnimation scale = new ScaleAnimation((float)1.0, (float)1.5, (float)1.0, (float)1.5);
        scale.setFillAfter(true);
        scale.setDuration(500);
        btn.startAnimation(scale);
```

Answer (score 1):

Snapchat Discover feature revolves around two Viewpagers. One ViewPager is vertical and another one is Horizontal ViewPager. Vertical View Pager is not by default supported by Android so you need Custom ViewPager such as :

[Vertical ViewPAger](https://github.com/castorflex/VerticalViewPager)

[Directional ViewPager](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-DirectionalViewPager)

Vertical Viewpager Consist of two fragments : **VideoViewFragment + HtmlContentFragment** .Each Vertical Viewpager will act as Stories .Now you can embed this Viewpager in default Android ViewPager (Horizontal).

For Video View fragment you can use Services of BrightCove Video Integration for Android .Brightcove will act as source of videos which you want to play from server.

HtmlContent can be directly fetched from server .